# AWS CDK deploy from circleCi fails with credential error but other aws services do not

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am running a cdk deploy build on circleCi, and when the step CDK deploy comes it gives me `"Need to perform AWS calls for account ************, but no credentials have been configured".`

But for the troubleshooting i tried other commands as well like
`aws s3 ls`
`aws aws cloudformation list-stacks`

These above commands we working fine, also able to run command to create a cloudformation with same config but not able to run cdk deploy. the access key and secret i am using has Admin access.

Comment: Do any of your stacks specify an environment explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the creds with a profile name using aws-cli Orb in CircleCI and
try using the below command to deploy with CDK

```
cdk deploy --all --profile cdkprofile
```

For reference, in CircleCI

```
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@2.0.3

commands:
  env-setup:
    description: AWS Env Setup
    steps:
      - aws-cli/setup:
          profile-name: cdkprofile
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

And assumption is AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are set as CircleCI env variables

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply, now i started getting: Reading existing template for stack CircleciTestStack.
Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account ************, but no credentials have been configured
    at SdkProvider.forEnvironment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/aws-auth/sdk-provider.ts:179:46

Comment: Can you post it as a separate question with your circleci config without which it is difficult to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

As a starting *note*: The best way to troubleshoot is with `cdk [command] --verbose` (see [CLI ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html))

CDK has an internal mechanism for [finding credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-environment) not directly using AWS CLI (AWS CLI is not a requirement for CDK to run)

In a similar situation with a CI tool, the issue was simply that the `~/.aws/credentials` *file did not exist* (not that you need it with AWS CLI, but in the situation for CDK, **it was required**)

Credit to this issue reporting: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6947#issue-586402006

Solution tested for above:

> For an EC2 running CI tool, with EC2 IAM role
>
> Where ~/.aws/config exists and defined profile(s) with:
>
> - credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
> - role_arn = arn:aws:iam:::role/role-to-assume-in-acctId
>
> Create empty ~/.aws/credentials file

Example error for the problem solved above (from verbose output)

```
Resolving default credentials
Notices refreshed
Unable to determine the default AWS account: ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure: Profile myprofile did not include credential process
```

Other causes found in other issues/comments could relate to:

- [Duplicate profiles](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6947#issuecomment-853568759)
- [Having credential_process](https://github.com/localstack/aws-cdk-local/issues/39#issuecomment-1022880426) in the profile, set to empty
- [Needing `--profile` parameter](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/228#issuecomment-870595516) to be added